# "I’ve seen a dozen times an instance"

Tags: word-order

Which one is correct?

> I’m also sort of puzzled. On the videos roaming around the YouTube I’ve seen a dozen times an instance where more than one person was present in a car.

> I’m also sort of puzzled. On the videos roaming around the YouTube I’ve seen an instance where more than one person was present in a car a dozen times.

Perhaps both are wrong?

Comment: The second is ambiguous as to whether you've seen them a dozen times, or they were present in a car a dozen times. The first is less ambiguous, though a bit more awkward. YouTube is treated as a proper name: I've never heard "the youtube". I also find "roaming around Youtube" bizarre when applied to the videos: videos normally stay in one place on Youtube. I think you mean "Roaming round Youtube, I've seen a dozen videos where... ", which applies "roaming " to the speaker, and also as it happens avoids your principal question.

Comment: I mean during my search for the videos on Youtube I encountered a dozen times videos that didn't match my personal preferences. On this basis I've deduced that during this time when I was roaming around youtube I've seen a dozen times an instance where more than one person was present in a car in the video. I don't know if I've explained it fairly well :).

Comment: minor thing: don't say "around the Youtube". simply, "around Youtube" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As Colin commented, the second sentence is ambiguous. It could easily be confused with meaning that you've seen people being present in a car a dozen times in the video. The first sentence is more easily understood.

Some other, minor corrections: YouTube is a proper noun so doesn't require a definite article. "Videos" isn't incorrect, but since everyone knows that YouTube is for videos, it's superfluous. The ordering of your phrases sounds a little awkward.

A more idiomatic sentence might be:

> I’m also sort of puzzled. A dozen times when I've been roaming around YouTube I've seen an instance where more than one person was present in a car.